Why in this case flex-basis: auto not resolved to the size of content?


.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;  
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.item-child {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1 0 100px;
}
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">
     <div class="item-child"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
     <div class="item-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>



In this snippet, .item-children's width value calculated to 100px, as it is set in their flex-basis property.
However, why .items themselves have width 50px each, shouldn't it be 100px as long as flex-basis: auto; forces them to borrow the width from their content and flex-shrink: 0; prevents their shrinking?

The flex-basis: auto on .item is constrained by the width: 100px on the parent. It cannot exceed that limitation under these conditions. Switch auto to min-content. Same thing. Automatically determined lengths are constrained by the parent dimensions.
On the other hand, .item-child has a defined width (flex-basis: 100px) and shrinking is disabled (flex-shrink: 0). So in this case, the item can exceed the width of the parent and main container.

I found out that if flex-direction: column;  is set on .container and .item than .items would have 100px height each, not 50px! Why is it working in the different way in this case? (I can ask another question if you wish)

Because you have .item and .item-child set to height: 100px in your code.
